# HTML5 Date pickers today stopped working in Salesforce1 on Android

Tags: salesforce1-app, mobile, html5, android, platform-bug

I have a Salesforce1 app that uses native HTML5 date(time) pickers. This wonderfully worked on all supported mobile platforms, on the desktop and in the one/one.app test page.

This morning (August 12th, 2014) it mysteriously stopped working on any Android phone.

To easily reproduce this I minimized my problem to this page:

```
<apex:page docType="html-5.0" standardController="CustomObject__c" >  
    <apex:form >
         <apex:inputfield value="{!CustomObject__c.DateTime__c}" 
                          type="datetime-local" 
                          showDatePicker="false" />                        
    </apex:form>    
</apex:page>
```

It even doesn't work with a pure html input tag:

```
    <input type="datetime-local"/>      
    <input type="datetime" />              
    <input type="date" />
```

I checked that neighter my Android phone nor its browser was auto updated. I also did not activly update my Salesforce1 app.

Can anybody out there reproduce and explain this behaviour?!

**EDIT: I am using a Google Nexus 5.**

Comment: As silly as this sounds, have you tried totally signing out and signing back in to the SF1 app?

Comment: Yeah sound silly ;-) Sure we tried that!

Comment: I opened case #10889926 with Salesforce support!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SFDC Support(Case #10889926) told me:

> Our R&D confirmed that this is already a known issue and is subjected
>   to be fixed in Winter 15 release (around October, subject to change).
>
> I have added the case BUG number to the case so that when the fix is
>   released you would be notified on the same.
>
> Please let me know if there are any further queries that needs to be
>   addressed, And i would be happy to assist you with the same.

It's not published on their Known issues page but,

> This is set to internal and not for customer facing, I would share the
>   BUG number though "W-2122749"
>
> This would be fixed with SF1 app version 6.0 which will be released in
>   winter 15.

Answer (score 3):

It's ridiculous because HTML5 date input works in regular Android browsers so they did something extraordinary to break it. I'm surprised you say "recently", [I've encountered it in June-July](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/16524051) and for me it was always broken (testing on HTC ONe X):

I've ended up conditionally including the [jQueryMobile's datepicker](https://github.com/arschmitz/jquery-mobile-datepicker-wrapper) and displaying either native date picker or text field + jQ M enhancements based on User Agent.

Now, obligatory self-promoting snippet: I'm getting my feet wet in GitHub. Not the first OS project I decided to give a go but with repo containing only initial commit and funny name (my  friend's idea) it doesn't look serious...

If you'd like to see my workaround: https://github.com/forceheroes/s1-widgets

Answer (score 2):

You are totally right.
Sadly, the field it is working at all in Android. ( But it is working in iOS, browser... )

Just tested your version with a custom object and also with opportunity object ( in Android and in iOS) , however none of them are working in Android app.

I also got a nice error like :
Unfortunately, Salesforce1 has stopped.!
Maybe the best way to move forward now, could be contact SF support and let them know. (Maybe create a case with them)  Sorry for the bad news :(

If you get it working please let me know! I'll keep an eye in the question!

[image: Pleease see image below]

Answer (score -1):

Try following code with modernizr to see if date inputs are supported, it will also alert the user agent of webview to give you more details:

```
<apex:page docType="html-5.0" standardController="Opportunity">  

<apex:includeScript value="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/1162324/test/modernizr.custom.35650.js"/>
<apex:form>
     Date : <apex:inputfield value="{!Opportunity.closedate}" 
                      type="date" 
                      showDatePicker="false" />                        
</apex:form>    

<script>
var debugInfo = 'UserAgent :' + navigator.userAgent + '\n\n\n';
debugInfo += (Modernizr.inputtypes.date ? 'Supports ' : 'Not Supports ') + ' Date Inputtype';
alert(debugInfo) ;


</script>

</apex:page>
```

BTW, I tried the same code on my Nexus 7 with and following is a screenshot of date picker coming fine and updating back as well.

So key question is which Android Device, OS and Browser you are on ?

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: iOS always worked. Android is the problem!

Comment: Umm... will try on android device and update back...

Comment: @RobertSösemann added findings for Android as well in the post.

Comment: I am using a Google Nexus 5.